# Django exclude past one to many relationships?

Tags: django

I am having some trouble with Django and running an exclude past a many to many query.

The following four Tables matter:

```
Status - name, id
TestcaseCategory - category, id
Testcase - category (Foreign key to TestcaseCategory), id, name...
TestcaseRun - testcase (Foreign key to Testcase), id, status (Foreign key to Status), start_date, end_date, ...
```

Obviously each TestCase can exist in a large number of Runs, each Run can have one Status, and each Testcase can have one Category, though there may be a large number of testcases per category.

The goal is to get the number of testcases per category that failed, in a time frame, but where not 'development' failures. These are well structured names:

```
PASS-DEV
FAIL
FAIL-DEV
...
```

I used to have many queries to do this, but we ended up with performance issues. As such we are trying to consilidate it into a single query:

```
excludeArgs = {"testcase__testcaserun__status__name__icontains": "dev"}
filterArgs = {"testcase__testcaserun__status__name__icontains": "fail",
              'testcase__testcaserun__end_date__gte': start,
              'testcase__testcaserun__end_date__lte': end}
categoryData = models.TestCaseCategory.objects.all()
categoryData = categoryData.filter(**filterArgs)
# Data exists here fine
categoryData = categoryData.exclude(**excludeArgs)
# Huh? Exclude has removed all of our results, when we expect there to be results!
# This happens even if I move exclude before the filter.
# if we did have anything left, we would do the following to get only the values we want:
categoryData = categoryData.annotate(fail=Count('testcase__testcaserun'))
categoryData = categoryData.values('category', 'fail')
```

This suggests I'm hitting a Django bug, or doing something not 'correct' for django. Which is it?

The answer below is wrong, but lead me to the correct answer:

```
categoryData = models.TestCaseRun.objects.\
exclude(status__name__icontains='dev').\
filter(status__name__icontains='fail', end_date__range=(start, end)).\ 
values('testcase__category').annotate(fail=Count('id')).order_by()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running the query on `TestCaseCategory`, the exclude is excluding the category, not the individual related items whenever there's a match. In other words, if there's at least one `TestCaseRun` with status containing "dev" in the category, the whole category is gone from your results.

However, this is the wrong approach anyways. You need to think from the perspective of what you're actually working with. You want the number of testcases by category, but that means we're talking about testcases, not categories.

Try:

```
TestCase.objects.\
    exclude(testcaserun__status__icontains='dev').\
    filter(testcaserun__status__icontains='fail', testcaserun__end_date__range=(start, end)).\
    values(category).annotate(Count('id')).order_by()
```

The important part is the `values(category).annotate(Count('id')).order_by()` bit. That will group the testcases by category and then run a count of how many are in each group. The result is a `ValuesQuerySet`, not an actual `QuerySet`, so you can't use it for anything else, but you will have your counts.

Comment: While the above isn't correct, it lead me to the correct answer for what I wanted.

I will put the proper code in the question.